# Extract a string value from code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the string : "Plan B Warranty & Breakdown Recovery"

from the following block of code. I am having problems locating it via xpath and get text. I would be grateful for some pointers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" ng-app="dan">
<head>
<body class="u-scroll-y ng-scope" ng-controller="CoreController as cc">
<div class="c-animate c-animate--show u-pos-f-t ng-hide" ng-show="global.alerts.length">
<div class="o-grid-fluid u-h-100 u-pl-0">
<div class="o-grid__row u-ml-0 u-h-100">
<div class="c-loader ng-hide" ng-show="loadingHome" style="">
<nav class="o-grid__col-xl-2 o-grid__col-lg-3 o-grid__col-xs-4 u-p-0 c-card__block u-h-100 u-shadowed u-pos-f-t ng-scope" ng-if="global.loggedIn">
<div class="u-p-0 u-h-100 o-grid__col-xl-10 o-grid__col-lg-9 o-grid__col-xs-8 u-pull-right" ng-class="{ 'o-grid__col-xl-10 o-grid__col-lg-9 o-grid__col-xs-8 u-pull-right' : global.loggedIn }">
<header class="o-layout-table__row u-bg-primary u-shadowed u-clearfix u-px ng-scope" ng-if="global.loggedIn">
<main class="o-view-container">
<div class="o-grid-fluid u-py-md">
<div class="o-grid__row">
<div class="c-animate c-animate--view-slide-in-right c-animate--view-slide-out-right ng-scope" ng-view="" style="">
<div class="o-grid__col-md-10 o-grid__col-xl-8 o-grid__col-xl-offset-2 o-grid__col-md-offset-1 ng-scope">
<div class="u-mb-lg u-text-center">
<h1 class="u-text-bold">Recommendations</h1>
</div>
<form class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required" name="recommend" ng-submit="recommend.$valid">
<div class="o-media c-card c-card__block u-shadowed u-mb-lg ng-scope" ng-if="rc.WarrantyEligible && !rc.prevWarranty()">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-px u-py-sm u-w-100">Warranty Options:</label>
<div class="c-form-group u-p-0 u-mb-sm u-clearfix">
<div class="o-grid__col-md-8">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-text-normal">Product Recommendations (Years):</label>
</div>
<div class="o-grid__col-md-4">
<input class="c-form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required" required="" placeholder="Years" ng-model="rc.recommend.year" min="1" max="3" type="number">
</div>
</div>
<div class="c-form-group ng-scope" ng-if="!data.answer_taxi">
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope" ng-if="!rc.planA && !rc.prestige" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('recommendation_warranty_plan_b')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.warrantyPlan" value="planB" name="warrantyPlan" type="radio">
<i class="c-option__radio"></i>
Plan B Warranty & Breakdown Recovery
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="o-media c-card c-card__block u-shadowed u-mb-lg u-text-body u-bg-success" ng-if="!rc.prevVap() && rc.VapEligible ">
<div class="c-form-group">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-px u-py-sm u-w-100">Vehicle Asset Protection Options:</label>
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('recommend_vap')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.vapPlan.plan" value="standard" name="vapPlan" type="radio">
<i class="c-option__radio"></i>
Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover
</label>
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('vap_key_facts_checked')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.vapCheck" name="vapCheck" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__checkbox"></i>
You confirm that you have received the VAP key facts leaflet?
</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="c-form-group">
<input class="c-btn c-btn--primary c-btn--block u-pull-right" value="Complete and Preview" ng-click="rc.complete(recommend.$valid); cc.utils.audit('recommend_complete')" ng-disabled="recommend.$invalid" type="submit">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js">
<script src="./build/app.js?v=2.13" defer="">
<script src="/build/standalone/jspdf.js" defer="">
<script src="/build/standalone/sigWebTablet.js" defer="">
</body>
</html>
```

ignore this ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the string `"Plan B Warranty & Breakdown Recovery"` you can use the following code block :

```
System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

As an alternative, you can try this code block as well :

```
WebDriverWait wait20 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement ele = wait20.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')]")));
System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: Corrected the xpath error, please let me know the status

Comment: Thank you both. Using the "Innerhtml" solution i can now extract the string from the result.

Answer (score 1):

First get the element by classname. Then get the text from it.

**EDIT:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')]"));  
String desiredText = element.getAttribute("innerHTML"); 
System.out.println(desiredText);
```

Comment: I think the text is attached to `label` tag.
`i` tag is closed and does not contain text

Comment: Bu using the provided html i got Success to get the desired String using the code above.

Comment: Hi Mark Let me know your feedback.

Comment: hi,
**response 1 failed :** SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')' is not a valid XPath expression. **response 2 failed :** no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"c-option__radio"}

Comment: @MarkH is there any other radio option in your page.

Comment: Yes...  But this will always be the first one.

Comment: hi,
it is not failing, but it is not returning any text.

Comment: Is it possible to paste full page html here. So that i can verify the code further. But the html you provided above works fine with my pc here.

Comment: @MarkH . Previous html is different from now. previously the text was in i tag and now i can see the tag is under label and resides in innerHTML part. See the edited answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160619/discussion-between-mahmud-riad-and-mark-h).

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath worked for me:

```
//input[@ng-model='rc.recommend.warrantyPlan']/following-sibling::i[1]
```

It's finding the associated input element, then grabbing the first i element after it.